# Reversing a template list

Tags: swift

I have the following definiton of a list

```
 class List<T> {
        var value: T
        var next: List<T>?

       func printList()
        {
          var currentValue = value 
          var nextNode = next
           print(currentValue)

          while (nextNode != nil)
          {

            currentValue = nextNode!.value
            print(currentValue)
            if(nextNode!.next == nil)
            {
              break;
            }
             nextNode = nextNode!.next

          }
        }
     }
```

and I wrote an extension to reverse the list like this :

```
extension List {
        func reverse() {

        var firstNode = self
         var previousNode: List<T>? = nil
        var currentNode = firstNode
        var nextNode = firstNode.next
        while nextNode != nil {
            currentNode.next = previousNode
            previousNode = currentNode
            currentNode = nextNode!
            nextNode = currentNode.next
        }
        currentNode.next = previousNode
        firstNode = currentNode



        }
    }
```

However when I tested out with sample list : `var mylist = List<Int>(value:1,next :List<Int>(value:2,next:List<Int>(value:3 , next :nil)))` 
when I reverse it and print it , it just prints "1 nil" .Any idea why the reverse function does not work as expected?

Answer (score 0):

Let's step through the code. I added the initializer that you left out:

```
init(value:T, next:List<T>?) {
    self.value = value
    self.next = next
}
```

And created a variable `f` to hold the list that you're using:

```
let f = List<Int>(value: 1, next: List(value: 2, next: List(value: 3, next: nil)))
```

so that `f` is now `{value: 1, next:{value: 2, next:{value:3, next:nil}}}`

Now let's look at what happens when we call `reverse()`:

```
var firstNode = self
var previousNode: List<T>? = nil
var currentNode = firstNode
var nextNode = firstNode.next
```

OK, so:

- `firstNode` is the entire list
- `previousNode` is nil
- `currentNode` is again the entire list
- `nextNode` is the tail of the list (i.e. `{value: 2, next:{value:3, next:nil}}`).

  ```
  while nextNode != nil {
      currentNode.next = previousNode
      previousNode = currentNode
      currentNode = nextNode!
      nextNode = currentNode.next
  }
  ```

So after one iteration:

- `currentNode.next` will get nil, which means `currentNode` is now just `{value: 1, next:nil}`
- `previousNode` will get `currentNode`, so again, `{value: 1, next:nil}`
- `currentNode` will become `{value: 2, next:{value:3, next:nil}}`
- `nextNode` will get the tail of that, i.e. `{value:3, next:nil}`

After the second iteration:

- `currentNode.next` will get `previousNode`, which is `{value: 1, next:nil}`
- `previousNode` will get `currentNode`, so it's {value: 2, next:{value: 1, next:nil}}
- `currentNode` becomes `{value 3:, next: nil}`
- `nextNode` gets the tail again, i.e. nil.

The loop stops at that point, because `nextNode` is nil. The next two lines are:

```
    currentNode.next = previousNode
    firstNode = currentNode
```

So now `currentNode.next` becomes {value: 2, next:{value: 1, next:nil}}, and `firstNode` is `{value 3:, next: nil}`. So you've kinda/sorta succeeded in reversing the elements, but:

```
f.reverse()
f.printList()
```

still only prints `1`. **What gives?!**

If you look at `reverse()`, you'll see that nothing that that code does changes the `value` field of any of the lists involved. Only the `next` field gets changed, and the `next` of `f` got set to `nil` in that first iteration through the list, when `currentNode.next` was set to nil. So when you print `f`, `printList()` prints out just `1` and then stops.

To solve the problem, you need to address the `value` fields of each of the sub-lists, not just the `next`.